# InfluxDB - 2.0 - stand alone DB

Tags: influxdb, influxql, influxdb-2

I am using Influxdb with Grafana for a while and I like it.
I am confused with the new version of Influxdb2.0. I was searching the doc and could not find useful info.

I have some questions.

1. Will Influxdb be available only as bundled with db + ui as 1 single binary going forward? Can we have standalone DB?
2. Will the Flux replace the current SQL like InfluxQL ? Or InfluxQL will also be supported.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. Yes, I believe the intention is to bundle the UI into the single binary so that it is always available with no additional installs. You can continue to use Grafana though - ignoring the bundled UI entirely*. There's no problem to ignore it so the DB is still "standalone". Since it is OSS, you could build a binary without the bundled UI if that is important for your use case.
2. InfluxDB 2.0 OSS is currently in RC0 (as of late Oct 2020). This version supports both [InfluxQL via a compatibility API](https://docs.influxdata.com/influxdb/v2.0/query-data/influxql/) (`/query`) and [Flux via the new `/api/v2/query` API](https://docs.influxdata.com/influxdb/v2.0/query-data/execute-queries/#influxdb-api) querying. The query and response formats are different. The docs have examples. In general, Flux is the direction InfluxDB is going.

*There may be some rough edges in the RC around configuring the first user without using the UI and only using the API. I have not tried this. I would expect the API to continue to improve is this area.